# Column has invalid length type error with parquet files

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, parquet

I have a list of parquet files that I am moving from one s3 bucket to another.
Before copying the parquet files to the destination bucket I am adding 2 columns.
We have a glu crawler that picks data from destination s3 bucket and populates it in redshift.
When I query the table in redshift I am getting the error **" column 'xyz' has an invalid type length. Expecting: 7 len in file: 6"**
the column which has the error has datatype decimal(15,7)
The is my code where I am first reading all parquet files to pandas dataframe and then adding extra columns and writing them back to parquet format. I googled the error and nothing was helpful.
my_parquet_list is the list of all parquet files

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
    for file in my_parquet_list: 
        bucket = 'source_bucket_name'
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        s3 = session.resource('s3')
        s3_obj = s3.Object(bucket,file)
        s3_obj.download_fileobj(buffer)
        df = pd.read_parquet(buffer, engine='pyarrow')
        df["col_new"] = 'aaa'
        df["date"] = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
        pq.write_table(table, buffer)
        new_file_name = file.split('/')[-1]
        bucketdest = 'destination bucket name'
        s3_file = 'folder path/'+new_file_name
        print(s3_file)
        s3 = session2.resource('s3')
        s3.Object(bucketdest, s3_file).put(Body=buffer.getvalue())
        print('loaded')
```

Comment: It looks like the difference in rows between output and expected is `7-6=1`? Does it have to do with headers? Are you reading in the data with no headers and writing it back with an additional row with headers?

Comment: @DavidErickson my data has headers, do I have to specifically mention headers i code

Comment: I am not sure... that was the only thing I could think of though. It doesn't look like there is a `read_parquet` param for that though.